# Orthogonal states evolution

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, quantum-information, vectors, quantum-states

I'm a bit little confused about orthogonality in QM.

1. $<a|b>=0$ what does physically mean?
2. Let's suppose that $<a|b>=0$ and for $t=0$ the system is in state a. Is there a possibility to find the system un state b as the time goes on? How can it be possible if the two states are orthogonal?

Answer (score 0):

1. Orthogonality measures the "overlap" between two vectors, and $\langle a|b\rangle$ means that the vectors $|a\rangle$ and $|b\rangle$ have no overlap.  What this means depends on the situation.  For example, if $|\psi\rangle$ represents the state vector of the system and $|E\rangle$ represents a state with definite (and non-degenerate, but that's not so important now) energy $E$, then $\langle E|\psi\rangle = 0$ means that the probability of measuring the system to have energy $E$ is zero.
2. Yes, it's possible. Over time the state vector of the system will evolve, and even if it is orthogonal to some other vector at $t=0$ there's no reason it would have to stay that way.